Excel is plotting scatter plot using the sequence of the points as the x-value and not the selected "x values"
I a trying to plot x and y values on a scatter plot with logarithmic axis. The x and y values are fairly random numbers, but when I try to plot them it plots the proper y-values, but the x-values are plotted as 1, 2, 3, 4...  (essentially counting up the number of data points I have instead of using the proper x values).
See incorrectly plotted graph

These are my data values and the series settings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

You have Text entries in column G (>100) is text and not numeric. You will need to replace them with either a real number positive number to have the X axis displayed as you want.

Thank you so much!!
